Injecting Lorentzian signal into random noise yielded only the peaks at the boundaries
I am currently trying to test the concept of keeping Lorentzian peaks from the random signal, by injecting the lorentzian signal first into a random signal, then perform a windowed FFT to filter out the lorentzian peaks, and then convolve the original signal with the signal after the windowed FFT filtering to leave only the Lorentzian peaks and filter out everything else. The code looks like following in Matlab:
%% Generate random noise signal
Fs = 1000;  % Sampling frequency (Hz)
T = 1/Fs;  % Sampling period
L = 10000; % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1) * T;  % Time vector
randomSignal = rand(1, L);  % Random noise signal

% Lorentzian function
lorentzian = @(x, c) c(2) / pi * (0.5 * c(1)) ./ ((x - c(3)).^2 + (0.5 * c(1)).^2);

% Inject a Lorentzian peak into the random signal
freqs = linspace(-Fs/2, Fs/2, L);  % Frequency range for Lorentzian
c = [50, 1e3, 0];  % Lorentzian parameters: width, amplitude, center frequency
lorentzianPeak = lorentzian(freqs, c);
lorentzianPeak = ifftshift(lorentzianPeak);  % Shift for time-domain compatibility
signalWithLorentzian = randomSignal + real(ifft(lorentzianPeak));

figure;
plot(randomSignal, 'r'); hold on;
plot(signalWithLorentzian), 'b', 'LineWidth', 1.5); % Plot the filtered signal
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Signal');
title('Signal with Lorentzian Peak');
legend('Random Signal without Lorentzian','Signal with Lorentzian');



%% Windowed FFT Analysis
% Window parameters and FFT setup
ffttime = 800e-2;  % 0.8 seconds window length for FFT
totaltime = length(signalWithLorentzian) * T;  % Total signal time
indx = t < ffttime;  % Index of signal within FFT time window
window = hanning(sum(indx));  % Hanning window of appropriate size

% Perform windowed FFT on data
fftav = zeros(sum(indx)/2 + 1, 1);
fftavfull = zeros(sum(indx), 1);
L_window = sum(indx);  % Length of the signal in the window
f = Fs * (0:(L_window/2)) / L_window;  % Frequency vector

% Windowed FFT loop
j = 0;
for i = 0:1000:(totaltime - sum(indx))
    indx_shifting = (1:sum(indx)) + i;
    
  
    
    data_segment = signalWithLorentzian(indx_shifting);

    
    data_segment = data_segment - mean(data_segment);  % Subtract mean
    print('data segment',data_segment);
    % Perform FFT and add to the running averages
    fftdata = abs(fft(data_segment .* window));  % FFT of windowed data
    fftdata2 = fftdata(1:L_window/2 + 1);  % Positive frequency components
    fftav = fftav + fftdata2;  % Average positive frequencies
    fftavfull = fftavfull + fftdata;  % Average full frequencies
    j = j + 1;
end



% Average FFT result
fftav = fftav / j;
fftavfull = fftavfull / j;

% Lorentzian fit on the FFT to detect and remove resonance peak
ParameterGuess = [50, 1e3, 0];  % Initial guess for Lorentzian fit parameters
fit_lorentzian = @(x, c) c(2) / pi * (0.5 * c(1)) ./ ((x - c(3)).^2 + (0.5 * c(1)).^2);
%fit_lorentzian = @(x,c) c(2)/pi*(0.5*c(1))./((x).^2+(0.5*c(1)).^2)+c(3);
lsqfit = @(c) sum((fftavfull - fit_lorentzian(f, c)).^2);  % Objective function for fminsearch

% Fit Lorentzian to the FFT result
opt = optimset;
lorentzianFitParams = fminsearch(lsqfit, ParameterGuess, opt);
lorentzianFit = fit_lorentzian(f, lorentzianFitParams);

% Remove Lorentzian resonance from the signal
fft_processed = abs(fftavfull ./ lorentzianFit');

% Calculate IRF (Impulse Response Function)
IRF = ifft(1 ./ fft_processed);
IRF = circshift(IRF, round(length(IRF) / 2));  % Align impulse response function

% Convolution with the original signal
filteredSignal = conv(signalWithLorentzian, IRF, 'same');

% Plot the results
figure;
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(t, signalWithLorentzian);
title('Signal with Lorentzian Peak');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(t, filteredSignal);
title('Filtered Signal (After Lorentzian Removal)');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');

I have been encountering the problem that fftdata = abs(fft(data_segment .* window));  % FFT of windowed data keeps returning 'NaN', and especially fft(data_segment .* window)returns all zero values.
When i plotted the signal with injected lorentzian, it seems that the only difference between the signal lorentzian peaks from the noise signal are the peaks at the boundaries, why is that?


The OP is asking why the resulting time domain function as the inverse FFT of function that is noise with a Lorentzian function in frequency added to it appears the way it does.
We can understand this from the basic Fourier Transform properties directly. The Fourier Transform and its inverse is linear, which means if we sum two signals, then the resulting transform will also be the sum of their individual transforms. Thus we can simply then ask what the inverse Fourier Transform of a Lorentzian function in frequency would be.
From most tables of Fourier Transforms (or we could derive it directly) we find the following relationship:
$$e^{\alpha|t|} \leftrightarrow \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2 + \omega^2}$$
Note how this matches the Lorentzian function in frequency when centered at $f=0$ is given by the OP.
The Inverse FFT is the discrete inverse Fourier Transform (with time domain aliasing if the time domain response did not decay quickly enough which is not the case here), where the upper half of the time samples equally represents that samples at negative time (we could use the ifft function to center time $t$ at $t=0$ if we desired).
